# Tessseract returns null in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocr, tesseract

Last month I started working on my leisure time to get some knowledge about Android OCR using Tesseract Library. I downloaded tess-two project & android ndk. Then I built that tess-two project on an ubuntu machine to create (.so) files and successfully got that. I just use that tess-two project with (.so) libs as library for my android project. (I am developing my project in windows 8).

Now I have an android project and tess-two project refered as Library for my project. Then I had done coding to get Image and pass it to TessBaseAPI object and get converted result in `getUTF8Text()` function But it takes too much time to convert but return null every time.

**This is my AsyncTask.After picture taken I will pass the image path here**

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
{
    private Context mcontext;
    TessBaseAPI baseAPI=new TessBaseAPI();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        File externalStorageDirectory = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory();
                baseAPI.init(externalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+
                "/ocrsample/tesseract/", "eng",TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
        inspectFromImagePath(picturePath);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent i = new Intent(mcontext, ReadActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("result", result);
        mcontext.startActivity(i);
        baseAPI.clear();
    }

    private void inspectFromImagePath(String picturePath) 
    {
        baseAPI.setPageSegMode(PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);
        baseAPI.setImage(new File(picturePath));
        String text = baseAPI.getUTF8Text();
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try send `result` from `onPostExecute()` to `ReadActivity` class that it's null because you return  `null` from `doInBackground`. so change return value to one value or initialize result in `onPostExecute()`